# JDO app engine: composite key

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

Is this the right way to define a composite key for
a class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
class Item {
  @PrimaryKey
  long id;
  @PrimaryKey
  String sellerID;
  // ... other fields follow
}
```

because I want the pair (id, sellerID) to be unique, not just id on its own.

Thus in the app engine datastore I need an entity which incorporates both
fields somehow into a key (for instance separating them with a dash and
concatenating them) but I am not sure about how to go about instructing
app engine to do so via JDO or even via the low-level API.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way here is to use KeyFactory and to use a single Key that you generate each time:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.Builder.html

Create a String Key and concatenate the two fields. Creating two @PrimaryKey annotations will not work - treat App Engine as close to a key-value store as possible. I really like Jeff Schnitzer's explanation here about how to think of the datastore as a HashMap/Dictionary:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts